# Building a binary search tree of strings in java

Tags: java, string, tree, binary-search-tree, treenode

I'm trying to build a tree of strings, but I seem to run into a few problems I'm not sure how to fix.

```js
   public static TreeNode buildTree(TreeNode t, String s)
   {
      int size = s.length();
      while(size > 0)
      {
         String current = s.substring(0,1);
         insert(t, current);
         s = s.substring(1);
         size--;
      }
      System.out.println("This is the tree:");
      System.out.println(t);
      return t;
   }
      /**************************
    Recursive algorithm to build a BST: if the node is null, insert the 
    new node. Else, if the item is less, set the left node and recur to 
    the left. Else, if the item is greater, set the right node and recur 
    to the right.   
    *****************************/
   private static TreeNode insert(TreeNode t, String s)
   {  
      if(t == null)
      {
         t = new TreeNode(s, null, null); 
         return t;
      }
      else
      {
         String s1 = (String) t.getValue();
         String s2 = s;
         //this line below is problematic
         if(s2.compareTo(s1) == -1 || s2.compareTo(s1) == 0) //s2 comes before s1
         {
            t.setLeft(new TreeNode(s2));
            insert(t.getLeft(), s);
         }
         else
         {
            t.setRight(new TreeNode(s2));
            insert(t.getRight(), s); 
         }
      }
      return t;
   }
```

Here's the class TreeNode:

```js
class TreeNode 
{
   private Object value; 
   private TreeNode left, right;
   
   public TreeNode(Object initValue)
   { 
      value = initValue; 
      left = null; 
      right = null; 
   }
   
   public TreeNode(Object initValue, TreeNode initLeft, TreeNode initRight)
   { 
      value = initValue; 
      left = initLeft; 
      right = initRight; 
   }
   
   public Object getValue()
   { 
      return value; 
   }
   
   public TreeNode getLeft() 
   { 
      return left; 
   }
   
   public TreeNode getRight() 
   { 
      return right; 
   }
   
   public void setValue(Object theNewValue) 
   { 
      value = theNewValue; 
   }
   
   public void setLeft(TreeNode theNewLeft) 
   { 
      left = theNewLeft;
   }
   
   public void setRight(TreeNode theNewRight)
   { 
      right = theNewRight;
   }
}
```

When I call the insert method from the buildTree method, and I try t = new TreeNode(s); or t= new TreeNode(s, null, null) when t==null initially, the tree stays null when it comes back to the buildTree. However, it seems to update the tree within the insert method. How could I fix this problem?

Also, there seems to be a problem with my compareTo's in the insert method, because it often returns this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Any help would be really appreciated because I've been stuck on this for quite a while!

Answer (score 0):

That is because the parameters are passed by reference in Java, so when yo do

```
t = new TreeNode(s, null, null);
```

you are assigning a new reference to t, not assigning a "value" to the received reference

Since you are returning t it should work if you do

```
t = insert(t, current);
```

Regarding the error you must have some case producing an infinite loop of calls to insert, you should be able to detect it debugging

Comment: I have a problem with the if(t==null) part, so just recursing like you did would not solve the problem but rather run into a runtime error due to infinite recursion, I believe (which happens to be the case)

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggest that designing a Class:TreeBuilder to build your string's tree then return it's head(one tree must have a headNode)。segregate the recursion method to another util class：Builder

```java
class TreeBuilder{
    private TreeNode head = null;                 // head Node

    public TreeNode buildTree(String source) {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            String current = String.valueOf(source.charAt(i));
            Builder.makeTree(head, current);
        }
        return this.head;
    }
}
```

2.Util class Builder

```java
class Builder{
    public static void makeTree(TreeNode head,String current) {
        if (head == null) {                 // make head first
            head = new TreeNode(current);
        }else {                             
            recurse(head, current);         // make body left
        }
    }

    public static void recurse(TreeNode temp, String current){
        if ( current.compareTo(temp.getValue()) < 1) {  // current <= tempNode
            if (temp.getLeft() != null) {               // tempNode has a smaller leftNode than itself
                recurse(temp.getLeft(), current);       // recurse left
            }else {
                temp.setLeft(new TreeNode(current));    // current smaller than tempNode
            }
        }else {                                         // current > tempNode
            if (temp.getRight() != null) {              // tempNode has a bigger rightNode than itselft
                recurse(temp.getRight(), current);      // resurse right
            }else {
                temp.setRight(new TreeNode(current));   // current bigger than tempNode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key to builder your tree is comparing current char with **headNode until one leafNode or innerNode**，missed in yor problematic block。

- if current smaller than tempNode，you should recurse the comparation with tempNode's leftNode[if exists a left Node]。because the leftNode is smaller than tempNode,you need to check out which one is smallest between current and leftNode and so on)
- and also,if current bigger than tempNode,you should recurse the right too

Comment: I think I've tried what you told me here, but I still get a null tree in the end...

Comment: focus on recuse method,debug it.there are some typing mistake in my codes and just got amended,you could try it again